# Does my cat have an attachment disorder and how to handle it?

Tags: psychology

We (Me and my wife and child) went away from 11 am on Wednesday until 3pm on Thursday. We discovered that our 8 year old Norwegian Forest Cat had not drunk or gone to the toilet the entire time that we were away. My wife's parents were home a lot  upstairs and he was familiar with them- he is often upstairs many times a day and plays with them some times. I think he ate some food. It is big worry that if we go away that he might become sick. He needs us to pour fresh water in his water bowl and possibly hold it for him- he doesn't like water fountains. Does my cat have a disorder? How can handle it.   He did all his toilet time about five minutes after we came home and soon after drank a lot of water.

Comment: I'm not too confident as to whether it is not normal. I think that the only way to ensure there is an actual problem is to repeat the separation.